# How to solve the issue of variables not picking up the create date time of the files?

Tags: powershell

Apologies if I make amateur mistakes as I am quite new to PowerShell.

Recently,  I was tasked to build a PowerShell Script to archive auto-generated files into folders based on their year (e.g., 2022) followed by their date range (e.g., 220601 - 220610). As there are many files in the source folder itself, I decided to use a foreach to loop through each individual file, noting that their creation date time may be different as well.

```
$FileCreationTime = $file.CreationTime
$YearMonthDate = $FileCreationTime.ToString("yyMMdd")
$MonthDate = $FileCreationTime.ToString("MMdd")
$YearMonth = $FileCreationTime.ToString("yyMM")
$Year = $file.CreationTime.ToString("yyyy")
$Month = $FileCreationTime.ToString("MM")
$Day = $FileCreationTime.ToString("dd")

$files = Get-ChildItem “C:\Test Folder\*.xml”

foreach($file in $files)
{...}
```

However, this method makes the variable `$FileCreationTime` to be the create date time of the folder (Test Folder) instead. Is there anyway to solve this? Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: Are you thinking that as the `foreach` loops around all of the definitions such as `$MonthDate`, `$YearMonth`, etc will be updated for each file?  If so, the definitions need to be inside the loop for that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$file` isn't defined at the beginning of your code sample. The variable assignments won't be updated per file, unless you move them **inside the loop body**:

```sh
$files = Get-ChildItem “C:\Test Folder\*.xml”

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $FileCreationTime = $file.CreationTime
    $YearMonthDate = $FileCreationTime.ToString("yyMMdd")
    $MonthDate = $FileCreationTime.ToString("MMdd")
    $YearMonth = $FileCreationTime.ToString("yyMM")
    $Year = $file.CreationTime.ToString("yyyy")
    $Month = $FileCreationTime.ToString("MM")
    $Day = $FileCreationTime.ToString("dd")

    # Now move the file into a folder based on e. g. $Year
}
```